# Product modification history (akeneo)

Tags: akeneo

Is there a way to generate a report of all the modified products and display what has been modified for each product without being forced to enter each product sheet and see in the history?

Comment: You are looking for an already built in tool or a way to achieve it yourself ?

Comment: it's the result that matters for me acctually but if there's a built in tool that would be better

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it by writing SQL query to database. I think for now Akeneo don't have built in tools to do this.

Comment: can you share your sql query please ?